# How to drive a HFBR-1541 optical transmitter?

Tags: driver, transmitter, optical-fibre

I want to drive a [HFBR-1541](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1791752.pdf?_ga=1.13313010.494937798.1481711472) optical transmitter (see page 7; 60mA output current), and I want the driver to have extended operating temperature range (at least starting from -20 degrees Celsius).

The driver recommended in the datasheet, [SN75451](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn75451b.pdf), does not meet the extended operating temperature range requirement and its corresponding version, SN55451, is not produced any more.

**Can somebody suggest a circuit or schematic to drive this transmitter and meet the operating temperature range requirement.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The industrial version of the [74F3037D](http://datasheet.octopart.com/74F3037D-Philips-datasheet-90551.pdf) goes from -40C to +85C and I have used it for driving a very similar device namely the HFBR-1414MZ: -

[image]

Three outputs were combined to share the load current. C65 was a speed-up capacitor. This was running at a data rate of tens of Mbps.